# How to capture event for all of these variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so this is my code:

```
let btnOne = $('.btn-one')
let btnTwo = $('.btn-twoo')
let btnThree = $('.btn-three')
```

I want to make some action when `any` of these buttons is clicked. How can I do that?

I've tried this

```
$(btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree).click(function (e) {
  // Some action
})
```

But it didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**PS. I only want to achieve this with variables.**

Comment: `btnOne.add([btnTwo, btnThree]).click(...)`

Comment: Or `$('.btn-one, .btn-two, .btn-three')`. Better yet, put a common class on all of them and select them in one call: `$('.btn');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I want to do it with variables...

Comment: Or put the comment event in its own function and `btnOne.click(handler);btnTwo.click(handler)...`

Comment: @haim770, please write this as an answer and I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Here's another:  `$( [ btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree ] ).each(function() { $(this).click(...) } );`  but it's a bit messy

Comment: By the way @haim's answer is not working.

Comment: @haim770 's answer needs some adjustment, but you can use `.add` : `btnOne.add(btnTwo).add(btnThree)`

Comment: Yup, correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the only option is to use the variables, you can combine them into an array and use `.each` to assign the event handler:

```
$([a,b,c]).each(function() { $(this).click(....
```

using the array with a `.click` directly doesn't work

```js
var a = $(".a")
var b = $(".b")
var c = $(".c")
$([a,b,c]).each(function() { $(this).click(function() { alert($(this).text()); }) });
```

```css
.a,.b,.c { border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100px; height: 1.25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>a</div>
<div class='b'>b</div>
<div class='c'>c</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `.add` to combine jquery collections (where each collection may only contain one element, it's still a collection), eg:

```
a.add(b).add(c).click(function() { ...
```

which uses chaining to add each additional variable

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable and getting hold of all them through class:

```html
<button id="btnOne" class="testButton">
One
</button>

<button id="btnTwo" class="testButton">
Two
</button>

<button id="btnThree" class="testButton">
Three
</button>
```

The script, simple enough:

```js
let btnElement = $('.testButton');

$(btnElement).click(function (e) {
  alert('Button Clicked');
})
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0Lj9b7t/

Answer (score 0):

what you can do here is that you can use common class for every button and then you can detect which button was pressed.Check out the following HTML and jQuery.

```js
$(".btn-one").click(function(e) {
  var button_number = $(this).html();
  alert(button_number + " pressed");
})
```

```html
<button class="btn-one">btn-one </button>
<button class="btn-one"> btn-two </button>
<button class="btn-one"> btn-three</button>
```

"*this*" that us used inside the click function will detect which button was clicked.
-thanks

Comment: Please read the comments under the question, this has already been suggested and rejected